# Auto focus is not working for input field

Tags: html, css

When I Press Login button one popup is shown.

In that popup I need default autofocus on Login Input field. Can I achieve that with HTML5/CSS only?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raghava0330/6f9ge64f/)

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="panel"> <a href="#login_form" id="login_pop" onclick="">Log In</a>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- popup form #1 --> <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="login_form"></a>

<div class="popup">
     <h2>Welcome Guest!</h2>

    <p>Please enter your login and password here</p>
    <div>
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" id="login" value="" autofocus />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Log In" /> <a class="close" href="#close"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: where is the fiddle ?

Comment: please add the code to stackoverflow too, not only in a fiddle.

Comment: tried javascript? element.focus() and element.select()?

Comment: Please stop removing edits instead of improving them since you do not seem to do what SO asks you and also paste the code from the fiddle

Comment: `document.getElementById("someId").focus()` or `<input type="text" autofocus>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The Answer is not really effectively (with certainty).**

I would suggest Javascript, as **UnskilledFreak** mentioned, on every click the focus is set

```html
...    
<a href="#login_form" id="login_pop" onmouseup="document.getElementById('login').select();">Log In</a>
...
<!-- not javascript library needed -->
<!-- tested on Win7 and Chrome 37+ -->
```

Here is your fiddle updated: **http://jsfiddle.net/6f9ge64f/2/**

You should probably also check key-input for people that don't use a mouse.

**Update:**

it's a bit hacky, but you could try

```html
...    
<a href="PATH-TO-FILE?c=1#login_form" id="login_pop" onmouseup="document.getElementById('login').select();">Log In</a>
...
<input type="text" id="login" value="" autofocus />
...
<a class="close" href="PATH-TO-FILE?c=2#close"></a>
...
<!-- tested with on Win7 and Chrome 37+ -->
```

where the `PATH-TO-FILE` is for example `http://www.test.com/default.html` (absolute or relative), and the `?c=1` and `?c=2` is any parameter, just to provoke a reload. like this you could use `autofocus`.

THIS WONT WORK IN JSFIDDLE since the HTML is embedded, but it works in the **"real-world"**.

**Update 2:**

```html
...
<a href="#login_form" id="login_pop" onmouseup="setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('login').focus()},10);">Log In</a>
<!-- tested with on Win7 and Chrome 37+ -->
...
```

Here is the fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/6f9ge64f/6/**

Comment: What didn't work? the first part or the hacky Version?

Comment: First Part @Winner_joiner

Comment: i just tried it again, in jsfiddle. i don't see the cursor, but when i start typing it works. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes @Winner_joiner. I need autofocus on that Login field.I am using Google Chrome

Comment: @raghava goud, i added another version, now setting the focus with an timeout, hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Yes it is working @Winner_joiner..Thank you very much

Answer (score 72):

`autofocus` is defined to work reliably only on page load. It is not really suited for situations where you are swapping, or opening, or unhiding DOM elements such as in a single-page application framework. You are likely to have to resort to handling the autofocusing yourself.

Comment: Thank you! It's weird because sometimes it works even not on page load...

Answer (score 5):

autofocus works only on standard pageload, If you are using javascript/angular/react/jquery to modify elements after page load the active element changes, and autofocus wont work.

What I do is I wait for all the dom elements to load and process then set the active element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $("#input-field").focus();
      }, 1500);
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery do something like this:

```
$( "#login-button" ).click(function() {
    $( "#input" ).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Autofocus attribute moves the focus to the specified input on page load. In this case #input is present in DOM but hidden; on clicking login button, the focus is removed.

Should probably use .focus() on the login click event handler

```
 <input type="text" id="login" value=""  />
 <input type="text" id="login" value="" autofocus />
 <input type="text" id="login" value=""  />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6f9ge64f/4/

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue in the past , i was trying to use `querySelector` on a `onClick` and toggling `focus()` on the selected input , after some trials I used `setTimeout` along with it and that got it working, it goes something like this

```
            ` setTimeout(  
                      () =>
                        (
                          document.querySelector(
                            '.some-input-field',
                          ) as HTMLElement
                        ).focus(),
                      200,
                    )`
```