# Input is only autofocused the first time

Tags: ember.js

I am still learning Ember and have encountered a problem with keep consistent behavior when showing/hidding certain elements in the template. I have the following controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  actions: {

    newCalendar: function() {
      this.set('showCalendarForm', true);
    },

    hideNewCalendar: function() {
      this.set('showCalendarForm', false);
      this.set('calendarName', '');
    },
    showCalendarForm: false,

    createCalendar: function() {
      var name = this.get('calendarName');

      if (!name) { return; }
      if (!name.trim()) { return; }

      var calendar = this.store.createRecord('calendar', {
        name: name
      });

      this.set('calendarName', '');
      this.set('showCalendarForm', false);
      calendar.save();
    },
  }

});
```

and a template

```
{{#if showCalendarForm}}
        <div class="input-group">
          {{input
            class       = 'form-control'
            id          = 'newCalendar'
            type        = 'text'
            placeholder = 'New calendar'
            value       = calendarName
            autofocus   = 'autofocus'
            focus-out   = 'hideNewCalendar'
            action      = 'createCalendar'
          }}
        </div>
      {{else}}
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" {{action "newCalendar"}}>New</button>
      {{/if}}
```

Problem is that the input field only gets autofocused the first time I click the button, and on subsequent clicks, the input gets displayed, but not autofocused. How can i fix this?

Comment: I doubt that dynamically adding an input element with the `autofocus` attribute will result in a reliable behaviour since this attribute is intended to autofocus on page load (=the elements exists in markup when loading the page). W3C: "`The autofocus content attribute allows the author to indicate that a control is to be focused as soon as the page is loaded, allowing the user to just start typing without having to manually focus the main control.`" [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control:-the-autofocus-attribute)

Comment: any idea on how i should it approach it then?

Comment: make the input=group a custom view. and focus the input in the 'didInsertElement' hook of the view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto focus is not working for input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313872/auto-focus-is-not-working-for-input-field)