# Strange behaviour of autofocus in html

Tags: html, cordova

I am currently programming a mobile application for an Android phone using the Apache Cordova framework.

In the app, there is a log-in view, where two input fields, [username] and [password], exist.

When I open the view without using the `autofocus` attribute, the cursor focuses automatically on the "#password" field. However when I use the `autofocus` attribute, the cursor actually focuses on the "#username" for a blink of an eye and then jumps to "#password".

Here is the markup demonstrating that behavior:

```
<input id="username" 
       required="required" 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="username" 
       name="username" 
       autofocus>
<input id="password" 
       required="required" 
       type="password" 
       placeholder="password" 
       name="password">
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: `autofocus` is meant to function when the page is loaded. Its behavior when element are added is unreliable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto focus is not working for input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313872/auto-focus-is-not-working-for-input-field)

Comment: @torazaburo This question is different. It appropriately uses autofocus on pageload, but the focus has weird behavior. The question you linked is trying to achieve a totally non-standard behavior from autofocus. Voting to Reopen.

Comment: @Maroben with that being said, the code above should not be behaving like you describe. Are you sure that's all the relevant code? You can only have one `autofocus` attribute per page (it's a Boolean), so if you have another one somewhere else on the page, you'll run into issues.

Comment: @TylerH The inputs are in two <li> elements, but this didn't make any difference. I am starting to believe that it is a JS problem, that some of my CoreView and CoreApplication Classes are interfering, but I really do not see how :/ There is a much more profound problem here. Anyhow thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Maroben in that case, use JSFiddle or a similar site (or a built-in Stack Snippet) to reproduce your error for us to see, and trim all the code that is not relevant/until the error stops appearing. That will help us answer the question, and there's a good chance it might help you discover the problem as well.

Comment: @TylerH The code is not that simple to just put it in JSFiddle, there are many dependencies between classes. If you are interested you could look it up on Github https://github.com/Maroben/MoblerCards.  It's an open source project I am working on. But do not bother yourself to much I most certainly will find the problem.

Comment: @Maroben I see. Best of luck! I'd look at `function callMyFocus(ev)` first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that some script is not running or your url (if have) does not end with #password anchor? Try to delete the id from password element or some other attributes to see if the reason is in some of those.

The last solution is to force the focus with JS, but this is not so good decision. When the page loads you can run:

```
$('input').blur(); //blur all inputs 
$('#username').focus(); //Focus whatever you want
```

or you can trigger the blur event

```
$('input').trigger('blur');
```

Comment: Yes, none of my JS code is invoking the input elements until I press the "login" button. How would you force it with JS?

Comment: When page loads you can run:

$('input').blur(); //blur all inputs
$('#username').focus(); //Focus whatever you want

or you can trigger blur event
$('input').trigger('blur');