# autofocus is not working on the sign up form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Focus property working on the sign-in but it's not working on sign up. when signup clicked, form for sign up opened through href. but autofocus is not working any of the fields in the sign up form.

```
<input id="pass_word" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass_word" pwcheck="pwcheck" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```

Comment: Could you please add example code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: <input id="pass_word" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass_word" pwcheck="pwcheck" autocomplete="off" autofocus> @NotABot

Comment: @errorau Same code I have mentioned above is working on sign in, But not on the signup

Comment: OP had put some HTML code in the question, but it was being interpreted so it was invisible. I escaped it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `autofocus` is defined to work reliably only on page load. It is not
>   really suited for situations where you are swapping, or opening, or
>   unhiding DOM elements such as in a single-page application framework.
>   [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27314017/6052427)

Also I created a basic example for you

https://jsfiddle.net/4c8k6vu1/

Comment: Then what else I can use for swapping the sign in to sign up?

Comment: Yes you can use

Comment: It is not suited for swapping right? Then what's the alternative?